# After database conversion from oracle to mysql, liquibase checksums are wrong

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, liquibase

We just converted our database from oracle to mysql. All the data were converted including the DATABASECHANGELOG.

Now, when running liquibase, many (not all) of the md5sums are different than what the database has. The data in the database are from running the liquibase changesets in oracle, and now we're running in mysql.

I have added a couple changesets to update the md5sums, and that moves me to the next changeset with a problem. This seems like an absolute last resort, and I think liquibase is supposed to work across different database drivers but maybe not like this.

For example, many changesets adding a column to a database table has a different md5sum, but changesets adding an index do not have a different md5sum. My reading suggests Liquibase generates these md5sums based on a database-agnostic representation of the changeset; is that right?

It's not a practical option to re-run all the liquibase at this point.

Comment: Let me know what could be better about this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update databasechangelog set md5sum = null;
```

This will clear all the md5sums which will be recalculated the next time you run liquibase.

According to my reading as well, liquibase should only use the XML to calculate the md5sum, but clearly something else is going on.Good luck!

Comment: right!? I have a Mysql and an oracle database set up, and run my java application against both. The md5sums are the same on both, but when running against mysql, liquibase complains about most entries!

Comment: Since the changelog was not shown, this is speculation, but if any of the change tags in a changeset reference an external file, then the contents of that file are also used as part of the checksum calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the response; in my case, no external files.